# Laravel Dusk error: Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

As the title says, I've go a clean install of Laravel 5.4 and the latest Homestead (1.0.1). However, when I run a simple Dusk test case I get the following error:

> Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

Anyone know how to deal with this? I tried changing the port to something else such as `8888` to no avail.

EDIT:
I've been able to dig a little deeper and found out that the `chromedriver` executable was not actually executable (`chmod`). Now that I've fixed that I get this error when I manually try to run it.

> ./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: For me it was enough to chmod the executable in `vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux`. There is also a macOS `chromedriver-linux` and windows `chromedriver-win.exe` version.

Comment: here is a discussion on the issue. https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/10

Comment: Are you run command `php artisan dusk` via SSH in your server or Homestead? you need `chrome browser` to run browser test, try to run command in host OS instead.

Comment: some reference run dusk in homestead http://www.jesusamieiro.com/using-laravel-dusk-with-vagrant-homestead/

Comment: I ran into the same issue while running php artisan serve, turns out that you cannot have the php artisan serve running when you start dusk

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libnss3-dev`

Comment: Can you please try to isolate the problem, i'm not a laravel developer but it looks like its not a php problem, you can try to connect to that port using telnet and see if its a laravel problem or the service you are trying to reach, you can also use postman(getpostman.com) to test. Hope this helps

Answer (score 14):

For those looking for a solution on Mac, I've just had to restart Chrome. Yes, Chrome, the browser. It seems it'd a pending update (it said that in the upper right corner).

Restarting it, and later chromedriver, make everything went fine

Comment: It required a full reboot, but that worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue today and the solution is on [Laracasts.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/can-i-run-laravel-dusk-on-my-forge-server#reply=327364)

Here's a copy.

```
# makes sure all your repos are up to date
sudo apt-get update

# chrome dependencies I think
sudo apt-get -y install libxpm4 libxrender1 libgtk2.0-0 libnss3 libgconf-2-4

# chromium is what I had success with on Codeship, so seemed a good option
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

# XVFB for headless applications
sudo apt-get -y install xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf

# fonts for the browser
sudo apt-get -y install xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base         xfonts-scalable

# support for screenshot capturing
sudo apt-get -y install imagemagick x11-apps

# Once all this has run through, you need to fire up xvfb on your homestead box. If you’re planning to # do this on a regular basis, you’ll want to get this setup on boot, but for the sake of testing things out:
Xvfb -ac :0 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu Linux 16.04, I got this to work:

**Install Chromium & dependencies for headless testing**

`sudo apt-get -y install chromium-browser xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable imagemagick x11-apps`

**Create a custom`DuskCommand`**

Which extends the original, with this `handle` method:

```
public function handle()
{
    $xvfb = (new ProcessBuilder())
        ->setTimeout(null)
        ->setPrefix('/usr/bin/Xvfb')
        ->setArguments(['-ac',  ':0', '-screen', '0', '1280x1024x16'])
        ->getProcess();

    $xvfb->start();

    try {
        parent::handle();
    } finally {
        $xvfb->stop();
    }

    return;
}
```

This will start Xvfb for headless testing before executing the tests and stop the process after testing completes.

Edit: And make sure `vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux` is executable.

Answer (score 2):

> Failed to connect to localhost port 9515 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Solution:

```
php artisan dusk:install
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 65
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears your chrome-driver installation is broken.

You can try to install it from scratch

```
CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`

wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
unzip ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/
rm ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you download the latest version of chrome driver and unpack it properly.

```
LATEST_VERSION=$(curl -s https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.co /$LATEST_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && sudo unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create a customDuskCommand**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class DuskCommand extends \Laravel\Dusk\Console\DuskCommand {

    public function handle() {
        $xvfb = (new Process(['/usr/bin/Xvfb', '-ac', ':0', '-screen', '0', '1280x1024x16']))
                ->setTimeout(null);

        $xvfb->start();

        try {
            parent::handle();
        } finally {
            $xvfb->stop();
        }

        return;
    }

}
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322930/470749. It was outdated and didn't work, so I'm providing an updated answer that works.

---

**UPDATE:**

I personally don't follow this approach anymore. After I deployed to production, I got this error: `E_ERROR: Class 'Laravel\Dusk\Console\DuskCommand' not found` because I'd forgotten that my `composer.json` only installed Dusk in the dev environment rather than also in production. If you adhere to the principle that "test code" shouldn't be deployed to production, then this approach of writing a custom class that extends `\Laravel\Dusk\Console\DuskCommand` probably is not for you (since the `DuskCommand` dependency won't exist in production).

<sub>I will leave this answer here anyway since it's hopefully a valuable warning to people. Please comment if you think I should delete it instead. By the way, Jonas Staudenmeir tends to have great answers, so [this looks interesting as an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56317334/470749).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If your tests were previously working and now you find one or two randomly getting this error (and not necessarily always the same one or two), this is likely down to Chrome automatically updating itself and making Dusk's Chrome binaries out of date. In this case running the following seems to fix the issue and make all tests go back to consistently passing:

```
php artisan dusk:install
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest laravel/homestead box v.6.0.0 it's working out of the box

https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead