# Laravel Dusk - Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I want to create a test which I will use from Controller so I write:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Modules;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Dusk\ElementResolver;
use Exception;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Laravel\Dusk\Chrome\ChromeProcess;

class TestController extends Controller {



  public function test() {

    $process = (new ChromeProcess)->toProcess();
    if ($process->isStarted()) {
      $process->stop();
    }
    $process->start();

    $options      = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--disable-gpu', '--headless', '--no-sandbox']);
    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
      ->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

          $driver = retry(1, function () use ($capabilities) {
      return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities, 60000, 60000);
    }, 50);

    $browser = new Browser($driver, new ElementResolver($driver, ''));
    $browser->resize(1920, 1080);
    $browser->visit('https://example.com/login')->click('#.btn > form > div.auth-form-body.mt-3 > input.btn.btn-primary.btn-block');
    $browser->driver->takeScreenshot(base_path('tests/Browser/screenshots/logged.png'));

  }


}
```

When I run this script using localhost:8000/test I got this message:

> Facebook \ WebDriver \ Exception \ WebDriverCurlException Curl error
>   thrown for http POST to /session with params:
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--no-sandbox"]}}}
>   Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

Current I use WAMP server on Win10 for local testing but then I will move the code on Linux Ubuntu 18.

Comment: I've spent the last 3 days trying to solve very similar.  I have not found a solution that works for me :(

Comment: There must be some way to run this from controller

Comment: @Watercayman Any idea what is the problem here?

Comment: For running Dusk in controllers, I've used - https://github.com/duncan3dc/dusk . I didn't dig into his code but it works pretty nicely

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir C:\wamp64\www\dusk-scraper>php artisan dusk:update --detect
Chrome version 74.0.3729.169 detected.

Comment: What version of the `facebook/webdriver` package are you using (`composer show`)?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir facebook/webdriver    1.6.0    A PHP client for Selenium WebDriver

Comment: Do "normal" Dusk tests work?

Comment: Yes, normal test works perfect

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Any idea or example how to solve my problem?

Comment: I just compared it to the code that works for me: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/356#issuecomment-375941569 You can try `retry(5,` instead of `retry(1,`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I tried but I got the same error: Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException thrown with message "Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193955/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-aleks-per).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't fully explain it, but this works for me on Windows:

```
$process = (new ChromeProcess)->toProcess();
if ($process->isStarted()) {
  $process->stop();
}

$process->start(null, [
    'SystemRoot' => 'C:\\WINDOWS',
    'TEMP' => 'C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp',
]);

[...]
```

Replace `<User>` with the name of your user directory.

Comment: Please try `retry(5,`.

Comment: Yes, and now I got: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)

Comment: Did you install Chrome on your Linux machine? Does it work on Windows?

Comment: no, on WInodws dont work... I install Laravel Dusk on Linux and into /vendor/laravel/dusk/bin folder I have chrome file

Comment: That's just the ChromeDriver. You also have to install the Chrome *browser*.

Comment: but why, where, how ?

Comment: why I need CHrome, there is no mention of that in Laravel DUsk documentation

Comment: I install Laravel Dusk on my VPS server - where I host few websites... so its not my local machine - CENTOS 7.6

Comment: I install Chrome on CENTOS 7.6 and seems that finally works there but on WIN 10 still dont work. btw. Many many thanks. If you have some idea why on WIN dont work please share with us

Comment: I still get the error with `retry(1,` but `retry(5,` works for me. Can you try a higher number?

Comment: I tried with 10 but dont work on Win... btw. what that code means and why we cant use retry(1, ...  ???

Comment: We have to wait until the ChromeDriver is started. It's similar to using `sleep()`.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks very much...  i will try to keep developing on CentOS