# I am trying to run Dusk in Laravel Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-dusk, laradock

[image: ,]

I followed all the steps as in documentation of Laravel but still no luck
And i am using Docker (laradock) in mac

Comment: have you tries this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040362/laravel-dusk-error-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-9515-connection-refused

Comment: I tired that but no luck and i am using mac

Comment: there is a issue similar to this on github laravel/dusk try this https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/649

Comment: I tried using it previously got solved by answer of staudenmeir in the issue mentioned above

Comment: also you should edit your answer to mention that you are using mac

Comment: @bhucho sorry none of these solved my problem

Comment: I have one more suggestion, you can try installing chromium browser, and set the platform, also have you tried with laravel homestead, you can also search for an issue which covers for docker and mac, if not found then you can raise a new issue, the new version is creating problems I don't know if they have resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a Mac, try installing Chromium with Brew:

```
brew install --cask chromium
```

This fixed the issue for me.